# Field Injection not working in dagger2 android

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am trying out my hands on dagger.Till now what i have understood is to inject dependency in one class we need to first dagger how that dependency is created through Modules or Constructor injection.Then use that dependency using Components methods.

Here is the sample code i am trying
War class depends on House1 and House2

War Class

```
public class War {

    @Inject House1 house1;
    @Inject House2 house2;

    public void startWar(){
        house1.prepareForWar();
        house1.reportForWar();

        house2.prepareForWar();
        house2.reportForWar();

        System.out.println("House1 is "+house1);
    }
}
```

House1 Class

```
public class House1 implements House {

    @Inject
    public House1() {
    }

    @Override
    public void prepareForWar() {
        System.out.println("House1 Prepared for War");
    }

    @Override
    public void reportForWar() {
        System.out.println("House1 reported for War");
    }
}
```

House2 Class

```
public class House2 implements House {

    @Inject
    public House2() {
    }

    @Override
    public void prepareForWar() {
        System.out.println("House2 prepared for war");
    }

    @Override
    public void reportForWar() {
        System.out.println("House2 reported for War");
    }
}
```

WarModule Class

```
@Module
public class WarModule {

    @Provides
    public War provideWarObject(){
        return new War();
    }
}
```

Component Class

```
@Component(modules = {WarModule.class})
public interface HouseComponent {
    War getWar();
}
```

Main Class

```
public class TempMain {

    public War war;

    public void startWar(){
        war = DaggerHouseComponent.builder().warModule(new WarModule()).build().getWar();
        war.startWar();
    }
}
```

Here Dagger knows how House1 and House2 are Created using Constructor and War Object through WarModule.

So In war class when @Inject House1 and @Inject House2 are used dagger should inject it as it knows how to create these dependencies.
But I am getting Null Pointer Exception here

Error : 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gosemathraj.dagger2.java.models.war.War.startWar(War.java:14)

Comment: Dagger wont inject your War dependencies because to do fields injection you need to create an inject method in the component and call it somewhere. Also, if you want  to provide your War object in a module, then just receive your House1 and House2 through the constructor and add them as parameters of your provide method.

Answer (score 1):

> So In war class when @Inject House1 and @Inject House2 are used dagger should inject it as it knows how to create these dependencies. But I am getting Null Pointer Exception here

Dagger won't do anything because *you* create the object here:

```
@Provides
public War provideWarObject(){
    return new War();
}
```

If you use an @Provides annotated method you need to setup the object before returning it. Dagger will only inject objects that it creates or where you call `component.inject(object)`.

The simples solution is to remove the `@Provides` annotate method and add a `@Inject public War() {}` to your class. Then Dagger can create the object and will inject it afterwards, the same thing you're already doing for your `House*` classes.

On an additional note, I don't know why you would use field injection over constructor injection, but you can move your dependencies to the constructor as well, allowing the fields to be private.